# Numeric or value error: character string buffer too small : ORA-0651

Tags: c#, oracle, api, stored-procedures

I created a Move Order by API but error I'm getting when I run procedure is: **Numeric or value error: character string buffer too small: ORA-0651**. I check a few suggestions in forums but none fixes my problem. I need your help.Thanks for your in advance.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE AAA_CREATE_MO(v_organization_id in   number,v_mrf_id in number, v_description in varchar2, v_mo_number out varchar2)
as
x_return_status VARCHAR2 (1);  
x_msg_data      VARCHAR2 (4000);  
x_msg_count     NUMBER;  
l_user_id       NUMBER;  
l_resp_id       NUMBER;  
l_appl_id       NUMBER;  
l_hdr_rec inv_move_order_pub.trohdr_rec_type :=   inv_move_order_pub.g_miss_trohdr_rec;  
x_hdr_rec inv_move_order_pub.trohdr_rec_type := inv_move_order_pub.g_miss_trohdr_rec;  
l_line_tbl inv_move_order_pub.trolin_tbl_type:= inv_move_order_pub.g_miss_trolin_tbl;  
x_line_tbl inv_move_order_pub.trolin_tbl_type:= inv_move_order_pub.g_miss_trolin_tbl;  
x_hdr_val_rec inv_move_order_pub.trohdr_val_rec_type;  
x_line_val_tbl inv_move_order_pub.trolin_val_tbl_type;  
v_msg_index_out NUMBER;  
l_cnt number     := 0;

l_rsr_type inv_reservation_global.mtl_reservation_tbl_type;  
l_code_combination_id gl_code_combinations.code_combination_id%type;  

CURSOR c_itm_onhand  
IS  
select *
from XXGSC_MRF_MO_INTERFACE
where mrf_id = v_mrf_id;

BEGIN  
SELECT user_id INTO l_user_id FROM fnd_user WHERE user_name = 'CONCSYS';  

SELECT fr.responsibility_id,  
fr.application_id  
INTO l_resp_id,  
l_appl_id  
FROM fnd_responsibility fr,  
fnd_responsibility_tl frt  
WHERE fr.responsibility_id  = frt.responsibility_id  
AND frt.responsibility_name = 'ISD-Inventory Super User'; --Responsibility  
fnd_global.apps_initialize (l_user_id, l_resp_id, l_appl_id);  

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Creating MO');  

--l_line_tbl.DELETE; 
FOR i IN c_itm_onhand  
LOOP  
l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
mo_global.set_policy_context ('S', i.organization_id);  
inv_globals.set_org_id (i.organization_id);  
mo_global.init ('INV');  


x_line_tbl.DELETE;  
l_hdr_rec.date_required               := SYSDATE;  
l_hdr_rec.header_status               :=  inv_globals.g_to_status_preapproved;  
l_hdr_rec.organization_id             := v_organization_id;  
l_hdr_rec.status_date                 := SYSDATE;  
l_hdr_rec.transaction_type_id         := inv_globals.g_type_transfer_order_issue; --Type:Move Order Issue  
l_hdr_rec.move_order_type             := inv_globals.g_move_order_requisition;  
   l_hdr_rec.db_flag                     := fnd_api.g_true;  
   l_hdr_rec.operation                   := inv_globals.g_opr_create;  
  -- l_hdr_rec.description                 := v_description; 
  -- l_hdr_rec.to_account_id               := i.ccid;  
  --l_hdr_rec.from_subinventory_code      := i.subinventory_code;  
  l_line_tbl (l_cnt).date_required          := SYSDATE;  
  l_line_tbl (l_cnt).inventory_item_id      := i.inventory_item_id;  
  l_line_tbl (l_cnt).line_id                := fnd_api.g_miss_num;  

l_line_tbl (l_cnt).line_status            := inv_globals.g_to_status_preapproved;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).transaction_type_id    := inv_globals.g_type_transfer_order_issue;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).organization_id        := i.organization_id;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).quantity               := i.qty;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).status_date            := SYSDATE;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).uom_code               := i.transaction_uom;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).db_flag                := fnd_api.g_true;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).operation              := inv_globals.g_opr_create;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).from_subinventory_code := i.subinventory_code;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).to_account_id          := i.ccid;  
--l_line_tbl (l_cnt).lot_number             := i.lot_number;  
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('===================================');  
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Calling INV_MOVE_ORDER_PUB to Create MO');  
--INV_MOVE_ORDER_PUB.PROCESS_MOVE_ORDER (p_api_version_number => 1.0, p_init_msg_list => fnd_api.g_false, p_return_values => fnd_api.g_false, p_commit => fnd_api.g_false, x_return_status => x_return_status, x_msg_count => x_msg_count, x_msg_data => x_msg_data, p_trohdr_rec => l_hdr_rec, p_trolin_tbl => l_line_tbl, x_trohdr_rec => x_hdr_rec, x_trohdr_val_rec => x_hdr_val_rec, x_trolin_tbl => x_line_tbl, x_trolin_val_tbl => x_line_val_tbl);   
  END LOOP;
  INV_MOVE_ORDER_PUB.PROCESS_MOVE_ORDER (p_api_version_number => 1.0, p_init_msg_list => fnd_api.g_false, p_return_values => fnd_api.g_false, p_commit => fnd_api.g_false, x_return_status => x_return_status, x_msg_count => x_msg_count, x_msg_data => x_msg_data, p_trohdr_rec => l_hdr_rec, p_trolin_tbl => l_line_tbl, x_trohdr_rec => x_hdr_rec, x_trohdr_val_rec => x_hdr_val_rec,  x_trolin_tbl => x_line_tbl, x_trolin_val_tbl => x_line_val_tbl); 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (x_return_status);  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (x_msg_count);  
  IF x_return_status = 'S' THEN  
  COMMIT;  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Move Order Successfully Created');  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Move Order Number is :=>>>>>>>>  '||x_hdr_rec.request_number);  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('===================================');  
  ELSE  
  ROLLBACK;  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Move Order Creation Failed Due to Following   Reasons');  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('===================================');  
  END IF;  
  IF x_msg_count > 0 THEN  
  FOR v_index IN 1 .. x_msg_count  
  LOOP  
  fnd_msg_pub.get (p_msg_index => v_index, p_encoded => 'F', p_data =>   x_msg_data, p_msg_index_out => v_msg_index_out );  
  x_msg_data := SUBSTR (x_msg_data, 1, 200);  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (x_msg_data);  
  END LOOP;  
  END IF; 
  v_mo_number := x_hdr_rec.request_number;
  END AAA_CREATE_MO;
```

Comment: what line number does the error message reference?

Comment: May I suggest using a breakpoint and stepping through your code. Is awfully difficult to help with out any reference. That error usually means that DBMS_output has run out of space. I would suggest. `DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE (buffer_size => NULL);`

Comment: @kevinsky error message reference at line 75

Comment: @Miguel will try your suggestion